# how can I add a checkbox to an alert dialog?

Tags: java, android

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
               // View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_checkbox, null);
              //  CheckBox mCheckBox = mView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                builder.setTitle("Agree Term and Policy");
                builder.setMessage("Legit’ However, ‘EXPERIENCES’ help;");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });

                builder.show();

                LayoutInflater eulaInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this);
                View eulaLayout = eulaInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checkbox, null);
                builder.setView(eulaLayout);
                CheckBox dontShowAgain = (CheckBox)eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp">

  <CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/checkBox"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Don't show this message again" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is dialog_checkbox layout. can i add check box inside dialog on place of setnegativebutton.i have try lot of thing nothing work and not show checkbox in alertdialog.

Comment: You can use Dialog and make custom layout according to your need..

Comment: can i add checkbox on place setNegativeButton

Comment: i have already made custom layout for check box in code

Comment: checkbox is not show on alert dialog

Comment: move builder.show() at last

Comment: Try using a custom DialogFragment (you can easily google for that).

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the dialog before setting the view so you get default dialog , show the dialog after setting the view . Also keep textview to show message and button for continue .

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);


                LayoutInflater eulaInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this);
                View eulaLayout = eulaInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_checkbox, null);
                builder.setView(eulaLayout);
                CheckBox dontShowAgain = (CheckBox)eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


                builder.show();
```

Comment: can you add your `dialog_checkbox` layout  in question

Comment: No , edit your question and add the contents in your  `dialog_checkbox` layout file

Comment: i have add checkbox inside linear layout

Comment: Ok , Please post the layout file else I cannot tell why you are not getting checkbox in dialog .

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Don't show this message again" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Did you set message, positive button to builder ? If yes then remove them and place them in the layout it self .

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setTitle(title_default);
        mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItems, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    mUserItems.add(position);
                }else{
                    mUserItems.remove((Integer.valueOf(position)));
                }
            }
        });

        mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                String item="";
                String no="";
                for (int i = 0; i < mUserItems.size(); i++) {
                    item = item + listItems[mUserItems.get(i)];
                    no = no + mUserItems.get(i);
                    if (i != mUserItems.size() - 1) {
                        item = item + ", ";
                        no = no + ", ";
                    }
                }
                button.setText(item);
            }
        });

        mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();
```

you can check my library for full implementation. [PrintArray](https://github.com/Tobibur/PrintArray)

Answer (score 0):

If you want like this:
[image]

You can use this code From KindaCode.com:

> ```
> // main.dart
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> void main() {
>   runApp(const MyApp());
> }
>
> class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
>   const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return MaterialApp(
>       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
>       title: 'KindaCode.com',
>       theme: ThemeData(
>         // enable Material 3
>         useMaterial3: true,
>         primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
>       ),
>       home: const HomePage(),
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> // Multi Select widget
> // This widget is reusable
> class MultiSelect extends StatefulWidget {
>   final List<String> items;
>   const MultiSelect({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MultiSelectState();
> }
>
> class _MultiSelectState extends State<MultiSelect> {
>   // this variable holds the selected items
>   final List<String> _selectedItems = [];
>
> // This function is triggered when a checkbox is checked or unchecked
>   void _itemChange(String itemValue, bool isSelected) {
>     setState(() {
>       if (isSelected) {
>         _selectedItems.add(itemValue);
>       } else {
>         _selectedItems.remove(itemValue);
>       }
>     });
>   }
>
>   // this function is called when the Cancel button is pressed
>   void _cancel() {
>     Navigator.pop(context);
>   }
>
> // this function is called when the Submit button is tapped
>   void _submit() {
>     Navigator.pop(context, _selectedItems);
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return AlertDialog(
>       title: const Text('Select Topics'),
>       content: SingleChildScrollView(
>         child: ListBody(
>           children: widget.items
>               .map((item) => CheckboxListTile(
>                     value: _selectedItems.contains(item),
>                     title: Text(item),
>                     controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
>                     onChanged: (isChecked) => _itemChange(item, isChecked!),
>                   ))
>               .toList(),
>         ),
>       ),
>       actions: [
>         TextButton(
>           onPressed: _cancel,
>           child: const Text('Cancel'),
>         ),
>         ElevatedButton(
>           onPressed: _submit,
>           child: const Text('Submit'),
>         ),
>       ],
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> // Implement a multi select on the Home screen
> class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
>   const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
> }
>
> class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
>   List<String> _selectedItems = [];
>
>   void _showMultiSelect() async {
>     // a list of selectable items
>     // these items can be hard-coded or dynamically fetched from a database/API
>     final List<String> items = [
>       'Flutter',
>       'Node.js',
>       'React Native',
>       'Java',
>       'Docker',
>       'MySQL'
>     ];
>
>     final List<String>? results = await showDialog(
>       context: context,
>       builder: (BuildContext context) {
>         return MultiSelect(items: items);
>       },
>     );
>
>     // Update UI
>     if (results != null) {
>       setState(() {
>         _selectedItems = results;
>       });
>     }
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         title: const Text('KindaCode.com'),
>       ),
>       body: Padding(
>         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
>         child: Column(
>           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
>           children: [
>             // use this button to open the multi-select dialog
>             ElevatedButton(
>               onPressed: _showMultiSelect,
>               child: const Text('Select Your Favorite Topics'),
>             ),
>             const Divider(
>               height: 30,
>             ),
>             // display selected items
>             Wrap(
>               children: _selectedItems
>                   .map((e) => Chip(
>                         label: Text(e),
>                       ))
>                   .toList(),
>             )
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Source: https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-making-a-dropdown-multiselect-with-checkboxes/